# How to store and search list of 'Banned Passwords'

Tags: java, dictionary, passwords

I'm working on a project where I need to have a set of password restrictions that includes a file of disallowed passwords (*All the common passwords like 'abc','abcdef','12345' 'password' etc.*) The file of passwords will consist of around 10000-15000 words.

Now I want to make sure that when a user sets/changes a password, it doesn't exist in the list. I was thinking of using a dictionary (or map) in Java (with buckets as 'A', 'B', 'C'.... 'Z','NUMBERS','SPECIAL_CHARS') so that I just check the first character and then search the corresponding bucket. But I'm not sure what kind of performance I can get out of this.

Any suggestions for working with a 'Banned Passwords' List.... Any other pointers to watch out for?

Answer (score 2):

If you extend your approach of "one bucket per letter" to the complete string, you will end with a [**trie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), which looks like a nice structure for this problem, though I can't see a reason for not using a single `HashSet` (after all, the verification cost is almost constant, and the hash set searches in the bucket where the password is supposed to be stored). Splitting the hash depending on the initial letter does not improve the performance in comparision with using a single set.

On the other hand, if your implementation is memory bounded, you could avoid storing some banned passwords and do a rule-guided verification (e.g. check if there are 4 consecutive characters that differ by one, as in "ghij", or check if they are fragments of a keyboard row, such as "yuiop"). Each rule will be equivalent to several banned passwords.

Comment: That was my first guess at it, but I'm not sure if a trie will be overkill for this or not... more so considering I'll have to store the whole trie in memory. (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: With a trie you could (in theory) save memory for similar strings such as `password1` and `password2` that share a common prefix. But then I realized that each node is an instance, and it contains an array/list of childrens... an it might require more memory if you have many different prefixes. 

Since password modification is not a very frequent task, I think that you could exchange some processor cycles for less memory overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a real lib to do this. For example.. https://code.google.com/p/java-dictionary-password-validator/

Answer (score 0):

you have to write a method which can check sequence of characters (Ex: abcdef) and same characters (Ex:111111) and all other constraints. Along with this any how you have to take a static List/Set variable which will hold all restricted strings.

Comment: sequences and identical characters are also part of the restrictions... but I figured it'd be easier to tackle those with regex rather than bunching them up with the dictionary

Comment: That's wt i am saying. You have to handle these sequesnces and same character strings within a method by using regx or looping. Only you have to store restricted strings inside that static list once and check using contains() method of list.